# Pass list of integers as parameters to Ember transitionTo()?

Tags: json, list, ember.js, transition

I'm trying to pass a list of integers (of the form [1,5]) as params in `transitionTo` in Ember 3.14.  I've verified that the list can be read within this function:

```
  afterModel() {
    this.transitionTo('newRoute', this.modelFor('lastLevel').list);
  },
```

But I always get this error:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

How should I transform the list so it will pass into transitionTo()?

Comment: can you show your `router.js`? You want explict model passing (and so not execute the `model()` hook), correct?

Answer (score 2):

I found the pretty simple solution.  I had to `join` the list into a string:

```
this.transitionTo('newRoute', this.modelFor('lastLevel').list.join(',');
```